# How to make server recognize global filenames

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel, fatal-error

Let's say the file and folder structure is as below:

1. public_html/interface/index.php
2. public_html/includes/EliteScript.php
3. public_html/interface/site/template.php

In 1st one, I should be able to put this 
    `require_once("includes/EliteScript.php");` and it must look for `includes/EliteScript.php` in the server, without forcing me to changing it to `../includes/EliteScript.php` in `public_html/interface/index.php`

In 3rd one, I should be able to put this `require_once("includes/EliteScript.php");` and it must look for `includes/EliteScript.php` in the server, without forcing me to changing it to `../../../includes/EliteScript.php` in `public_html/interface/site/template.php`

I don't exactly know how to explain, but hoping you will understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Make sure that your include path has `public_html/` in the path then

Comment: That didn't help.
Even if it has worked, I don't want it. coz there are alot of pages mate, hard to change in all, it's giving a new error when changed :(

Comment: Your include path should be changed in one place, and one place only, and that's in your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) file; clearly you didn't change it correctly if it's giving you an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OVER HTACCESS:

```
php_value include_path '/FULL_PATH/public_html'
```

OVER PHP:

set your include_path

```
set_include_path( '/FULL_PATH/public_html' );
```

or add it to your existent paths:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/FULL_PATH/public_html');
```

if you dont know your current path:

```
echo dirname( __FILE__ );
```